# How is the better way to resolve a ternary that if true return false?

Tags: javascript, validation, operators, conditional-operator

I have a flag that could be true or false that is validating a ternary, then the if true return false otherwise return any value from variable.

```
const validation = flag ? false : isValid;
```

This validation seems weird, I want to know if exists another way to improve this validation.

Comment: You can read this code as: "If flag is true, then validation = false, otherwise validation = isValid." There's nothing wrong with this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems clear to me, but if you want another way to write it:

```
const validation = !flag && isValid;
```